# How to underline gaps created with CSS columns property?

Tags: html, css

I want to underline and separate a number every two digits.

Here is what I tried and its [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WgRs6/1/):

**CSS**

```
.number {
    width: 8em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    columns: 5;
    -webkit-columns: 5;
    -moz-columns: 5;
    column-gap: 0.2em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0.2em;
    -moz-column-gap: 0.2em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="number">0102030405</span>
```

As you can see in the demo, the spaces created every two digits are not underlined.

How can I underline them ?

**NOTE:**

I'm looking for a solution compatible with Chrome,  Firefox, IE and Safari.

Comment: One way (might be considered a hack) to achieve this result is to simply remove the `text-decoration` and instead give it `border-bottom: 1px solid black;`.

Comment: Either use a `border` or `before`/`after` elements to fake it, or use a different method to space the digits.

Comment: would love to see if this is possible with just CSS

Comment: @Nit can you provide some sample code in an answer please?

Comment: @TylerH The bottom line goes too far (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WgRs6/3/)

Comment: @uchamp Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25627771/363573

Comment: Thanks for tagging me @Stephan. I used Nit's CSS in your fiddle and didn't see what you were asking for. Is it working for you in Chrome? I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the additional `position: relative` on `.number`.
[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/15qmrtyz/).

```
.number {
    width: 8em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    columns: 5;
    -webkit-columns: 5;
    -moz-columns: 5;
    column-gap: 0.2em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0.2em;
    -moz-column-gap: 0.2em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    position: relative;
}

.number:before {
    background: black;
    bottom: 3px;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Can you comment your answer? Why do you use `position: relative`? Is it possible to use `em` everywhere instead of `px`?

Comment: 1/ pseudo exists only if content property is set 2/ It's made the size needed 3/ It's then absolutely positioned to (by definition) its closest ancestor that is positioned 4/ Better be the element itself (its "parent") so `position: relative`

Comment: @Nit Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera were the other two browsers I tested.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific with versions, for example it works just fine for me in Firefox.